# How to add additional attributes to tag with content_tag in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Given:

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class => "alert-box alert" do %>
  <%= flash[:error] %>
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
<% end %>
```

I wish to obtain at runtime (notice the "**data-alert**" attribute):

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">
  <!-- flash error output -->
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

What do I add to the content_tag to make this work?

Comment: `:data => {:alert=>""},` gets the job done, but it looks crude.
Is it the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class => "alert-box alert", :data => {:alert => nil} do %>
  <%= flash[:error] %>
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your answer also works. (note my comment above)
Which would be the best way? :data => {:alert=>""} or :data => {:alert=>nil}?